# Push Data to Existing Table in BigQuery

Tags: java, sql, google-bigquery

I am using Java and SQL to push data to a Timestamp partitioned table in BigQuery. In my code, I specify the destination table:

```
.setDestinationTable(TableId.of("MyDataset", "MyTable"))
```

When I run it, it creates a table perfectly. However, when I attempt to insert new data, it throws a BigQueryException claiming the table already exists:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: 
Already Exists: Table MyProject:MyDataset.MyTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some documentation digging, I found a solution that works:

```
.setWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
```

Adding the above appends any data (even if it's duplicate). I'm not sure why the default setting for .setDestinationTable() is the equivalent of WRITE_EMPTY, which returns a duplicate error. The google docs for .setDestinationTable() are:

> Describes the table where the query results should be stored. If not
>   present, a new table will be created to store the results.

The docs should probably clarify the default value.